# Should I use a global boolean variable in this case?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, global-variables, uialertview

I have a viewcontroller(say A). I am pushing some viewcontrollers over the first viewcontroller(A). After some tasks, I am switching back to my first view controller(A). That is, I pop to rootviewcontroller(A). But this time my viewcontroller(A) should have an alertview.

My question: Is setting a global boolean variable the right way to go in this case. I mean, I declare a global boolean variable which sets to true, only when the viewcontrollers are popped out. Is there a better way I could do this.

Comment: I will use boolean variable in this case. But I can't say that's the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you may use Global NSString(or BOOL) for showing the AlertView when comes to ViewController
Here in Below code i used the String variable.
Declare a NSString variable in AppDelegate.h Class

```
NSString * checkAlert;
//make property of that NSString.
@property(retain,nonatomic)NSString * checkAlert;
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
//synthesize checkAlert
@synthesize checkAlert;

checkAlert=@"NotNeed";
```

then in ViewController

```
-(void)ViewWillAppear{
// here check if checkAlert contains string as you want
if(checkAlert isEqualToString:@"showAlert"){
 //here show the AlertView
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"AlerViewmessage" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
}

//when you abou to navigate to another ViewController the Access that checkAlert String    as
-(void)goToAnotheViewController{
AppDelegate* appdele=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appdele.checkString=@"showAlert";

//then navigate to viewController
[self.navigationController pushViewController: animated:YES];
}

//you just need to compare checkString's value string .
```

It'll work

Comment: @SAHARA please refer this http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also save it in `NSUserDefaults`.
In a ViewController:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"some_key"];
```

in an other ViewController in the `viewWillAppear` for example:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults  standardUserDefaults];
BOOL val = [prefs boolForKey:@"some_key"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also **set your first view controller as a global variable**, e.g. in your AppDelegate, then you can access it via

`(YourAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].firstViewController`

and then call a DisplayAlert function on it after popping back to it.

Or you can **pass the first view controller** to all subsequently pushed view controllers as 'master view controller' and then call the function without need of a global variable.

Or you can **access the root view controller** by calling

`[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]`

and then call the alert function on it.